# Agrupar funcionários por empresa em query

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou fazendo um relatório, onde preciso seguir o seguinte layout:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com a query abaixo, acabou se criando mais linhas, ao invés de agrupar os funcionários por empresa:

```
select e.cnpj as cnpj,
       e.nome_completo as empresa,
       li.cod as solicitacao,
       ''  funcionarios
       from liberacoes li,
                  empresa    e
             where
                 li.cnpj = e.cnpj and
                 li.dt_acesso_ini = curdate()
union all

select '' as cnpj,
       '' as empresa,
       '' as solicitacao,
       f.nome_completo as funcionario
                                     from funcionarios f,
                                          empresa      e
                                     where
                                         f.cnpj = e.cnpj
                                     order by 1 desc;
```

Me trazendo esse resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em uma query apenas eu consigo fazer o layout de saida ficar igual ao que preciso seguir?

**UPDATE**

Tentei a query abaixo, mas o resultado ainda está fora do que preciso:

```
  select
       li.cod,
       e.cnpj,
       e.nome_completo as empresa,
       coalesce(f.nome_completo,'X') as funcionario
   from empresa e
   left outer join funcionarios f on f.cnpj = e.cnpj
   left outer join liberacoes li on li.cnpj = e.cnpj
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

você não precisa do union nesse caso:

```
   select distinct
       e.cnpj,
       e.nome_completo as empresa,
       coalesce(f.nome_completo,'X') as funcionario
   from empresa e
   left outer join funcionario f on f.cnpj = e.cnpj
```

Comment: Não deu certo amigo, o resultado ficou igual.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, veja como ficou o resultado.

Comment: coloca a estrutura das tabelas, e tente utilizar o SQLFiddle

Comment: coloquei um distinct ali, faz um teste

Comment: obs. O agrupamento pro nome da empresa aparecer apenas uma vez, para n funcionários, é feito na hora da exibição, assim, para cada funcionário o nome da empresa irá aparecer mesmo no resultado da query